# empty page style on first page of scrartcl

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrartcl

A document using class `scrartcl` by default includes a page number on every page, including the first. What is the easiest way to suppress the typesetting of the page number on the first page (which, of course, is always "1")?

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after `\maketitle`?

Answer (score 1):

Change `\titlepagestyle` to `empty`:

```latex
\renewcommand\titlepagestyle{empty}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass
  %[titlepage]
  {scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}\author{Author}
\renewcommand\titlepagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This works even if you use class option `titlepage`.

If there is no `\maketitle` in your document, then you can use `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after `\begin{document}`.